# Javascript: converting very large and very small numbers to a fixed human readbale string

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have the following function which I thought would convert very large e.g., `1e+24` and very small, e.g., `1e-18` numbers to a fixed string, e.g., 1000000000000000000000000:

```
    convertExponentialToDecimal (exponentialNumber) {
      // Sanity Check - i.e., is it exponential number?
      const str = exponentialNumber.toString()
      if (str.indexOf('e-') !== -1) {
        const exponent = parseInt(str.split('-')[1], 10)
        return exponentialNumber.toFixed(exponent)
      }
      if (str.indexOf('e+') !== -1) {
        const exponent = parseInt(str.split('+')[1], 10)
        return exponentialNumber.toFixed(exponent)
      }
      return exponentialNumber
    }
```

However, for very large numbers - the process seems not to be working ...

i.e., a conversion of 1e+24 yields 1e+24, but 1e-18 yields 0.000000000000000001 as expected.

Can anyone spot the obvious issues, or have any pointers or even their own working solution for such a scenario...

If this is any insight - it works for anything less than 1e+21 ...

Comment: The digits parameter to `.toFixed()` works from 0 to 20.

Comment: You might try `.toPrecision()` instead.

Comment: Also you can use something like `Math.ceil(Math.log10(n))` to get the (possibly negative) number of digits you need.

Comment: @Pointy ooo so close, `.toPrecision()` gives 999999999999999983222784 for 1e+24 and

Comment: Well recall that JavaScript numbers are *base-2* floating point values, and they do not afford infinite precision.

Comment: I guess I could do something like a string extraction...

Comment: The problem is that the raw material you're looking for is not actually there in the number. For large exponents, low-end digits don't exist. There's only room for 51 bits of binary fraction, which is not even 16-digits worth of decimal digits.

Comment: If you're happy with having zero digits after some point, you could do that with something like the answer just posted, though it would probably take some tweaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 'very large' part:

```
  if (str.indexOf('e+') !== -1) {
    let [a,b] = str.split('+')
    a = a.slice(0,-1)
    if (a.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
        b = parseInt(b) - (a.length - a.indexOf('.') -1)
    }
    return a.replace('.','')+"".padEnd(b,0)
  }
```

For your 'very small' part (though this would need to be tested, it works on my example but i didn't go through corner cases) :

```
if (str.indexOf('e-') !== -1) {
  const [a,b] = str.split('-')
  return '0.'+a.slice(0,-1).padStart(b,0).replace('.','')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Number type is IEEE754 float with double precision behind the curtain and it doesn't have enough precision to represent 1e24 digits. If you want to avoid treating numbers as strings, consider [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) data type.

There are BigInt literals with `n` suffix and they don't support exponential notation, but luckily they do support `**`. For big numbers, you can use

```
10n**24n; // 1000000000000000000000000n
```

BigInts, are Int, without decimal point. But they are also Big, so you can afford fixed point notation, like *first thousand digits are integer part, second thousand digits decimal part* (the maximum size depends on available memory).